# Add gltf-model to a-frame scene via three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, aframe, gltf

How to **load gltf-model to a-frame scene via three.js** loader directly using javascript, not a-frame tags?

The model will have animation, and further I would like to control this animation via three.js too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A few places that could be of help: The gltf-model component code, it uses the three.js loader: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/gltf-model.js Also Don's animation mixer: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/loaders/animation-mixer.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a [component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/component.html#register-a-component), which consists of the three.js [gltf loader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader), like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("model-loader",
   init:function() {
   //three js loader code + attaching it to the entity's object3D
   }
});
```

Since i had trouble with multiple animations using the [khronos exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF), If you want to have many of them try using [three.js JSON](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/JSONLoader).

If you have trouble with any of the steps, i'd say each of them require separate attention, so please create less broad questions.

Comment: thanks it works, edit please brackets and semicolon at the end :)